# How to add new point (image) on double click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael, double-click

I have javascript function (that uses Raphael) that on click select area. And I need to add new function that on double click:

- add new image (small image that symbolizes point)
- add some text field next to this image (point) so that user could add description to this point
- add remove button next to image and text field. So that if user woluld like to remove it he could. It should remove this whole new point(image) with text field
- I need to also know cordinates of this new point, so that I could save it

Here is code of my javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function () {
        var R = Raphael("paper", 500, 500);
        var attr = {
            fill: "#EEC7C3",
            stroke: "#E0B6B2",
            "stroke-width": 1,
            "stroke-linejoin": "round"
        };
        var area = {};
        area.Element1 = R.path("...").attr(attr);
        area.Element2 = R.path("...").attr(attr);
        ...
        area.Element63 = R.path("...").attr(attr);                                 
        var current = null;
        for (var state in area) {
            area[state].color = Raphael.getColor();
            (function (st, state) {
                st[0].state = 0;
                st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
                st[0].onmouseover = function () {
                    current && area[current].animate({ fill: "#EEC7C3", stroke: "#E0B6B2" }, 500) && (document.getElementById(current).style.display = "");
                    st.animate({ fill: st.color, stroke: "#ccc" }, 500);
                    st.toFront();
                    R.safari();
                    document.getElementById(state).style.display = "block";
                    current = state;
                };
                st[0].onmouseout = function () {
                    if (this.state == 0)
                        st.animate({ fill: "#EEC7C3", stroke: "#E0B6B2" }, 500);
                    else
                        st.animate({ fill: "#C05219", stroke: "#E0B6B2" }, 500);
                    st.toFront();
                    R.safari();
                };
                st[0].onclick = function () {
                    st.animate({ fill: "#C05219", stroke: "#E0B6B2" }, 500);
                    st.toFront();
                    if (this.state == 0)
                        this.state = 1;
                    else
                        this.state = 0;
                    R.safari();
                };

            })(area[state], state);
        }
    };
</script>
```

I am not a javascript programmer so I don't really even know where to start. So any help here is  much appreciated!

Comment: Please add the source of the JavaScript function as well as the HTML, at least the part that is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manage to make it work using more simple javascipt than Raphael. Here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function () {
        var R = Raphael("paper", 500, 500);
        var attr = {
            fill: "#EEC7C3",
            stroke: "#E0B6B2",
            "stroke-width": 1,
            "stroke-linejoin": "round"
        };
        var area = {};
        area.Element1 = R.path("...").attr(attr);
        area.Element2 = R.path("...").attr(attr);
        ...
        area.Element63 = R.path("...").attr(attr);                                 
        var timer;
            var firing = false;
            var singleClick = function () { };
            var doubleClick = function () { };
            var firingFunc = singleClick;
            var counter = 1;           

            for (var state in area) {
                area[state].color = Raphael.getColor();

                (function (st, state) {
                    st[0].active = 0;
                    st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";

                    st[0].onclick = function (event) {
                        if (firing) {
                            var relativeX = event.pageX;
                            var relativeY = event.pageY;                          
                            $('.marker').append('<div class="pin_container" style="top:' + relativeY + 'px; left:' + relativeX + 'px;"> <input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" class="pin_textbox"><input type="button" id="remove" class="delete_button" value=" "></div>');
                            counter++;
                            $(".delete_button").click(function () {
                                $(this).parent().remove();
                            });                       
                            firingFunc = doubleClick;
                            if (st.editable == true) {
                                if (this.active == 0) {
                                    this.active = 1;
                                    st.animate({ fill: "#C05219", stroke: "#E0B6B2" }, 500);
                                    st.selected = true;                                    
                                }
                                else {
                                    this.active = 0;
                                    st.animate({ fill: "#EEC7C3", stroke: "#E0B6B2" }, 500);
                                    st.selected = false;                                                                    }
                            }
                            R.safari();
                            return;
                        }

                        firing = true;
                        timer = setTimeout(function () {
                            firingFunc();                                                   
                            firingFunc = singleClick;
                            firing = false;
                        }, 250);
                        if (st.editable == true) {
                            if (this.active == 0) {
                                this.active = 1;
                                st.animate({ fill: "#C05219", stroke: "#E0B6B2" }, 500);
                                st.selected = true;
                                //st.toFront();
                            }
                            else {
                                this.active = 0;
                                st.animate({ fill: "#EEC7C3", stroke: "#E0B6B2" }, 500);
                                st.selected = false;
                                //st.toFront();
                            }
                        }
                        R.safari();
                    };
                })(area[state], state);
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear, especially the use of RaphaelJS. This is how you can add an image using RaphaelJS.

HTML

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var paper = Raphael("target", 320, 200);
var image = paper.image("https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png", 10, 10, 116, 41);
```

For button and all you can use HTML elements, and place it in the div **target** over RaphaelJS svg.

Comment: I am using Raphael to draw and select areas. Now I need to add functionality of adding 'pins'. Imagine that you have map of USA states and you can select whole state or add pin (like on google maps) for city or some other location.